# Identifying leading line space - Shell script

Tags: linux, shell, shell-script, text-processors

I have a sample file like below. There are leading whitespaces. Is there a way to detect them and print the exact line number which contains the whitespace using a shell script?

```
test space at back 
 test space at front
TAB at end  
    TAB at front
```

Comment: What have you tried to so far? You could probably use `grep` in some way I think.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
awk '/^[ \t]+/ {printf NR ", "}' test.txt
```

The above command will print the line numbers which have leading space(s) or tab(s) of the file `test.txt`

Comment: You're welcome! If this answer solved your problem, please accept it by clicking on the check mark.

Answer (score 1):

A version which would use the same regular expression as the one supplied by Farahmand but using `grep` instead of `awk` could look like this:

```
grep -n -E $'^[ \t]+' test.txt
```

The `$` is necessary to escape/interpret the `\t`.